# How can I add hours in Google Sheets to show days?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have 2 cells in Google Sheets with values:

```
22:00:00
22:00:00
```

and I have a cell which has the function **sum** to sum these values and it shows the value:

```
20:00:00
```

I am guessing it is trying to tell me 1 day + 20 hours, but how can I see the 1 day part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing calculations on date/times is tricky, because there are a lot of other parameters that you usually don't think about. Are the two times in the same time zone, for example? Or on which date are the two times?

I see that you want `22 hours + 22 hours` to be displayed as `1 day + 20 hours`, which sounds reasonable enough, but that assumption fails as soon as a day is *not* 24 hours - as it can be, when going from/to daylight savings time.

So I think the best you can get is to show the *number of hours* (`44`). However, it does not make much sense to format the *sum* cell as a date (which date? January 1st?), but as a *duration*: 
[image: Format: Number: Duration]

Feel free to look at/copy [the example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xTjI84BQOY3_ZYM4OmpUnQ6K2INT4igJ97rUzN1dk8g/edit?usp=sharing) I've set up.