# How do I do simple time calculation in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a *really* simple question, I have searched online and for the life of me, cannot work out how to do this:

1. Calculate the total hours and minutes from a start time to a finish time?
2. Calculate the grand total hours and minutes?

I’ve shared the document below, please feel free to copy & edit if you have the correct answer?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K6NkBzcfdpWSkVThw48BXy52LWWwV4T6VEul2LuDqsU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You might find this useful: [How can I add hours in Google Sheets to show days?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72739/how-can-i-add-hours-in-google-sheets-to-show-days/72747#72747)

Comment: This could be of interest as well: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59871/29140

Comment: Thanks Vidar, I'll have a look at that link. Thanks also Jacob, but I already check that page and this did not work on my spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks pnuts, I've tried your code in the link (still there) but unfortunately that does't work either.

Comment: @Darren try formatting the output cells as 'duration' when using pnuts' formula. Alternatively, also try: =mod(C3-B3,1) and drag down. For the grand total a simple sum should do.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Some of these work, but only up until 12:00, after that when you gt into 1am+ it stops working. Any ideas on how to deal with that? I've updated the spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry, just checked again and it works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=mod(C2-B2,1)
```

and drag down as far as needed. Make sure the format the cells as duration.
For the 'total time' a simple sum should suffice.